# Is logarithm of a matrix a monotone function

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms

Let $A$ be a positive definite matrix and let
\begin{align}
B \succeq \log(A)
\end{align}

Is it true that $e^{B} \succeq A$?

Also, if $A\succeq C$ is it true that
\begin{align}
\log(A) \succeq \log(C).
\end{align}

In the last one we do not claim that $C$ is psd.

I would also appreciate if someone can point me to a good reference on this subject.

Comment: How do you define the logarithm? Is it a unique logarithm of some kind, or are the results supposed to hold for all possible logarithms?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta This the usual logarithm of a matrix. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix

Comment: That page says that the logarithm is typically not unique. And it's certainly not unique for all positive definite matrices.

Comment: a reference with relevant proofs is http://dx.doi.org/10.7153/jmi-07-08. Also https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/1893-10.pdf might be of interest

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key phrase to look up is "operator monotone".  The (principal branch) logarithm on positive definite matrices is operator monotone, but exponential is not.  For example, 
try

$$A = \pmatrix{e & 0\cr 0 & 1\cr},\ \log(A) = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 0\cr},
\ B = \pmatrix{2 & 1\cr 1 & 1\cr}$$

You will find that $B \succeq \log(A)$ but $\exp(B) \not\succeq A$.

EDIT:

$$ \exp(B) \approx \pmatrix{ 10.3247023472592 & 5.47549688301169\cr 5.47549688301169 & 4.84920546424751\cr} $$

$$\exp(B) - A \approx \pmatrix{7.60642051925920 & 5.47549688301169\cr 5.47549688301169 & 3.84920546424751\cr}$$
which is not p.s.d. as it has determinant $\approx -.702390689773839$.

Comment: Thanks. Any references that you might suggest for me to look up?

Comment: I think one of the standard references is Horn and Johnson, "Topics in Matrix Analysis".

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Is the above obvious? It took me a while to verify that $e^B \not \ge A$